# Auto startup an executable application when downloaded from an email

Tags: c

I am building an application with C language for my final project,
I am sending the executable application via email,
when the application is downloaded it should run itself.

Comment: There are very good security reasons that isn't going to happen

Comment: U mean the application can t bypass the security,firewall or antivirus will detect it and remove it totaly ?

Comment: Why would SO users wish to involve themselves in your immoral/illegal actions?

Comment: If it's illegal..it depends on your MORAL
For me no :)

Comment: Unfortunately the alphabet-soup agencies, (FBI, CIA, NSA etc), lawyers, prosecutors and judges are extremely unlikely to believe that anyone helping you to achieve what you ask for is not liable to some extent for any damage that you may cause.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. This is to stop viruses/malware etc. to spread.

Comment: So no alternative way .
it s impossible ?

Comment: @NarutoKawasaki no it is not. The only way is if you have found a security vulnerability in an operating system.

Comment: Okay thank you @MateHegedus